# How Can I Make The Slideshow stop on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, carousel, slideshow

Here is the code i have in js.I tried doing some thing i saw on the internet but that eneded up just making the slideshow not work at all .

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
setTimeout(showSlides, 5000); // Change image every 5 seconds
}


</script>
```

Comment: Can you share what you did try and why it didn't work? In general, you'd need an `onmouseover` event handler and you'd need to keep track of the `setTimeout` handle that advances the next slide, but we probably need more context and information to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `clearTimeout(id)` to stop the timeout on mouse hover. Then start the timeout again on mouse leave. You can get the id with `let id = setTimeout(...)`

You can use event listeners for checking if the mouse is on the slides

```
let id = setTimeout(...)

slides.addEventListener("mouseover”, function (e) {
    clearTimeout(id)
})

slides.addEventListener("mouseout”, function (e) {
    id = setTimeout(...)
})
```